# Haskell Turtle Script: How to consume Shell

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

```
import Turtle
import Prelude hiding (FilePath)
import Data.Text hiding (find)
main = do
  f <- view $ format fp  <$> find (suffix ".mp4") "/Users/me/videos"
  procs "ffmpeg" ["-vn","-acodec","libmp3lame","-ac","2","-ab","160k","-ar","48000","-i"] empty
```

Basically I want to feed all the video filenames to ffmpeg.
Two questions:

1. How to combine the `procs` with `Shell` streams?
2. ffmpeg takes two inputs: one for `-i` and one for the output filename. What is the best practise to implement this with Turtle?

I've seen the [foldIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4/docs/Turtle-Shell.html) function that looks promising. But I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `view` like that. You use that to *run* a `Shell`, and it prints the resulting values and makes them inaccessible to you. `Shell` itself is a monad, so you should build up a `Shell` action, then run with with `view` or `sh` (to discard the values without printing). (They're terminal functions; you use them only when you're done doing what you're doing). In fact, `MonadIO Shell`, so anything you can do in `IO` you can do in `Shell` (via `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`).

```
main = sh $ do -- You don't want to print the output of this Shell (a bunch of ()s)
  filename <- format fp <$> find (suffix ".mp4") "/Users/me/videos"
  let output = findOtherName filename -- Find the output arg for ffmpeg
  procs "ffmpeg" ["-vn","-acodec","libmp3lame","-ac","2","-ab"
                 ,"160k","-ar","48000","-i",filename,output  ] -- Just add them on
```

This is comparable to

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for filename in /Users/me/videos/*.mp4; do
    output="`findOtherName "$filename"`"
    ffmpeg -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 -i "$filename" "$output"
done
```

Comment: Immensely helpful. I actually figure it out already. Could you also give me a hint on how to generate the output file names? I want to change from mp4 to mp3. I can't figure out how to use the sed command to do the substitution.

Comment: I wouldn't use `sed`. Just use the `Text` library's functions. `init filename <> "3"` should do it (`init` takes all but last character (all but the last `'4'`), `<> "3"` adds a `"3"` on the end).

Comment: Smart!. How about if the `procs` raises an exception? How to manage that exception and throw some messages and continue the process to other files? @HTNW

Comment: `procs` throws the `ProcFailed` exception on failure. `proc` will give you the error code and let you deal with it. [See the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4/docs/) for details.

Comment: Is it possible to do parallel processing on those files? @HTNW

Comment: @osager I'm not sure. Check the docs. You might be able to use `forkIO`, but don't quote me on that.